# Getting a PHP E_ERROR message, how to fix it?

Tags: wordpress

How can I fix this?

Error Details:

> An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 47 of the file /home/giraudodfw/www/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/core.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function et_() in /home/giraudodfw/www/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/core.php:47

Line 47:

```
$post_id = (int) et_()->array_get( $_GET, 'post', 0 );`
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12784048#12784048)

Comment: Just tried to locate this line 47 in FileZilla, then opened the core in Atom but I have no idea how to fix it 

Comment: PHP is telling you that the function `et_()` doesn't exist. Make sure it's not a typo and that the function has actually been defined somewhere so you can use it in your script.

Comment: That function is in the Divi theme core. Do not try to fix it in your editor. Download the Divi theme files again and replace what you have. You might just have a missing or corrupt file.

Answer (score 2):

logging via FTP, renamed divi folder (theme) to divi_old 
Now go back to Wordpress themes deleted the Divi theme and uploaded it again, installed it, After going to the settings, permalinks saved twice.
I think it can work...